# Holo theme for button

Tags: android, styles, themes

I am using this Code in style.xml file to apply to all Button in the App as i dont want to apply the whole Holo Theme :

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
 <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Custombutton</item>
 </style>

<style name="Custombutton" parent="Widget.Button" >
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

 </resources>
```

This Code Generate R.java errors, i am sure the error come from this code because when i remove it i have no error,

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: you have <resources> tag on top right ?

Comment: Of course <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources></resources>, i have two files style.xml, one in the values folder & the second in values-v11, this code is from the second file in the values-v11  folder because my app Target Sdk is set to 8, i have already tried to change to 11 with no luck

Comment: Just giving R.java errors ?

Comment: Android development, has some issues with capital variables, rename your `Custombutton` to `customButton` ... clean the project and build again...

Comment: @ozi yes only. - i have tried to rename & clean the project with no luck, when i remove this Code & Save the file, there is no Errors

Comment: @SmokCol  do you use Holo theme or Theme.Black ?

Comment: Theme.Black & i want to uses the Holo Button

Comment: @ozi The Error come from this Line : `<style name="custombutton" parent="Widget.Button" >`

Comment: Using this Code, i have Errors : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="custombutton" parent="Widget.Button" />
 
</resources>`

Using this one, No Errors : 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>


 
</resources>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, Replaced this :

```
 <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
```

By This :

```
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
```

I have the btn_default_holo_dark.png in my Drawable Folder